# Disable valueChange due to a writeValue

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor, angular15, angular-controlvalueaccessor

On my angular component, which implements `ControlValueAccessor`, I'm having a problem with fields getting blanked.  I'm doing this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this.formGroup.get('name')?.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
       this.formGroup.patchValue(version: null)
   })
}

writeValue(...) {
   this.formGroup.setValue({
      name: ...,
      version: ...
   })

   this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()
}
```

If they update the name, they have to pick a new version.  My problem is that when `writeValue` gets called, that triggers the `valueChanges` operations, and so even though I gave a version, the version is always empty.

How do I work around that?

Comment: I do not face to the same issue, can you please check ?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rhgbwe?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @paranaaan Your example isn't a `ControlValueAccessor` so your `writeValue` method is never actually invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent `valueChanges` from being called by passing an additional object to your `setValue` call as so: `{ emitEvent: false }`

Comment: I tried that as well.  When change detection runs it seems to be invoking the `valueChanges` event.  I'm really confused as this only happens sometimes.